# Trying to experiment with some logic in Arduino, how do I make it work?

Tags: arduino

I am learning to code in arduino.
I am trying to write a code, where I have a number of bottons and from A1-A4 there is a OR logic gate that activates (LED). but if A1-A4 & B0 is high There is and AND gate that activate (LED).

the code is below, let me know what I could do different

```
int pin_A0 = 26;
int pin_A1 = 22;
int pin_A2 = 23;
int pin_A3 = 24;
int pin_A4 = 25;

int pin_B0 = 40;

void setup() {

  pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A1, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(pin_A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_A1, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_A2, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_A3, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_A4, INPUT);

  pinMode(pin_B0, INPUT);

}


void loop() {


  if ( (digitalRead(pin_A1 || pin_A2 || pin_A3 || pin_A4) == HIGH) ) {
    digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);
    return;    
  }
  if ( (digitalRead(pin_B0) == HIGH) && (digitalRead(pin_A1 || pin_A2 || pin_A3 || pin_A4) == HIGH)){
    digitalWrite(A1, HIGH);
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

With `digitalRead(pin_A1 || pin_A2 || pin_A3 || pin_A4) == HIGH` you are using logical OR on those values, then trying to read that pin. What you are doing is:

```c++
digitalRead(22 || 23 || 24 || 25) == HIGH
```

And `22 || 23 || 24 || 25 = 1` since there is at least one non-zero (truthy) value. So you are doing this:

```c++
digitalRead(1) == HIGH
```

Instead, you have to do:

```c++
if ((digitalRead(pin_A1) || digitalRead(pin_A2) || digitalRead(pin_A3) || digitalRead(pin_A4)) == HIGH) { ... }
```

And since `HIGH = 1` (truthy) and `LOW = 0` (false) you can drop the `== HIGH` part:

```c++
if (digitalRead(pin_A1) || digitalRead(pin_A2) || digitalRead(pin_A3) || digitalRead(pin_A4)) { ... }
```

You can use less code (DRY) by storing the value:

```c++
void loop()
{
    bool a_button_pressed = digitalRead(pin_A1) || digitalRead(pin_A2) || digitalRead(pin_A3) || digitalRead(pin_A4);
    bool b_button_pressed = digitalRead(pin_B0);

    // Note: boolean values converted to int will be 1 or 0
    digitalWrite(A0, a_button_pressed);
    digitalWrite(A1, a_button_pressed && b_button_pressed);
}
```

Note: this will turn the leds off when the conditions are false, or 0, which is LOW.